# jQuery and HTML5 tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently developing a HTML5 page, so I want to use jQuery for some effects. Here's my code that doesn't seem to work:

The html code:

```
        <nav id="mainNavigation">
        <!--....-->
        </nav>
```

and now jQuery:

```
$('#mainNavigation').click(function(){
   alert("test");
});
```

For some reason, nothing is happening. When I try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("test");
})
```

everything works fine.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What browser are you using? Does it support html 5?

Comment: is click handler inside the document.ready?

Comment: It doesn't work in the current firefox, so in google chrome. @Birey: No.

Comment: Your code appears to be working - http://jsfiddle.net/Nw9xy/ What browser are you viewing this in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you aren't wrapping your code in a document ready. This is basically telling the code to run with the DOM is ready.

Are you doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mainNavigation').click(function(){
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

As per motoxer4533's comment you can also do this via jQuery's shorthand Document ready:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mainNavigation').click(function(){
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

Comment: For some context your javascript was loading into the page, but you weren't telling it when to run. It's a best practice to use a DOM ready event. You could also use a self executing closure, but your JavaScript would run as soon as you go to the end of the closure which may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: Just for the sake of saying so, you can shorten this to `$(function(){ ... });`

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('#mainNavigation').click(function(){ 
     alert("test"); 
   });  
})
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('#mainNavigation').live('click', function(){
       alert("test"); 
   }); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#mainNavigation').live('click', function(){
       alert("test"); 
   }); 
})
```